# Why this simple booktabs code does not work?

Tags: tables, booktabs

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{SSSS}
        1& small copper ring & small aluminum ring & large aluminum ring \\ \midrule
        $T$ [s]& $0.567\pm0.014$ & $0.570\pm0.004$ &$0.558\pm0.008$ \\
        $M$ [g]& 27.5 & 8.5 & 25.0 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{$T$ denotes for the average period, written together with the sample standard deviation. $M$ denotes for the mass of the ring.
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

then it throws some errors like:
Missing $ inserted. $T$ [s]& $0.567\pm0.014$ &
and others. What is the problem?

Comment: You forgot a closing brace after `mass of the ring.`, and `S` is not a predefined column type of `booktabs`. If you use e.g. `\begin{tabular}{cccc}` it works. `siunitx` defines an `S` column but it does not make much sense to use it for text entries.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot a closing brace after `mass of the ring.`, and `S` is not a predefined column type of `booktabs`.Here are two possible ways to to arrive at tables that compile.

1. If you use e.g. `\begin{tabular}{cccc}` there is no error.
2. `siunitx` defines an `S` column but it does not make much sense to use it for text entries, so you might also want to use `\multicolumn`s for the relevant headers.

Examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx} %<- defines an S column type but it may not make too
% much sense to use it here for all cells.
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        1& small copper ring & small aluminum ring & large aluminum ring \\ \midrule
        $T$ [s]& $0.567\pm0.014$ & $0.570\pm0.004$ &$0.558\pm0.008$ \\
        $M$ [g]& 27.5 & 8.5 & 25.0 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{$T$ denotes for the average period, written together with the
    sample standard deviation. $M$ denotes for the mass of the ring.}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{cSSS}
        1& \multicolumn{1}{c}{small copper ring} & 
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{small aluminum ring} & 
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{large aluminum ring} \\ \midrule
        $T$ [s]& 0.567\pm0.014 & 0.570\pm0.004 &0.558\pm0.008 \\
        $M$ [g]& 27.5 & 8.5 & 25.0 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{$T$ denotes for the average period, written together with the
    sample standard deviation. $M$ denotes for the mass of the ring.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: As [pointed out by Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536714/why-this-simple-booktabs-code-does-not-work/536715?noredirect=1#comment1356011_536715), one can simplify the code for the second table to

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{cSSS}
        1& {small copper ring} & 
            {small aluminum ring} & 
            {large aluminum ring} \\ \midrule
        $T$ [s]& 0.567\pm0.014 & 0.570\pm0.004 &0.558\pm0.008 \\
        $M$ [g]& 27.5 & 8.5 & 25.0 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{$T$ denotes for the average period, written together with the
    sample standard deviation. $M$ denotes for the mass of the ring.}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You don't actually need `\multicolumn` in the `S` columns, it's enough to put braces around the text, e.g. `{small copper ring}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks a lot! I did not know that.

Comment: @TorbjørnT there has been situations where it was needed. Though I don't recall if Joseph has fixed them